# Facebook share button works but the post message shows me an error

Tags: angular, facebook, share

I'm using a library called ngx-sharebuttons for Angular 8, the buttons are working fine, but when I try to share a link, the post message shows me the URL of my website and a description saying "error", and I'm trying to figure it out how to solve this problem, its weird because the link actually works when I share the post on facebook

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSmO3.png)

Thats my code:

```
<button class="share-btn" shareButton="facebook" url="{{urlinvite}}/view-invite/{{invite.code}}"><img src="/assets/images/profile_facebook.png" width="20" height="20" /></button>
```

I tried to use the tags [description] and [title], but facebook no longer supply both tags. And I tried to use meta tags like this:

```
  <meta name="title" content="Title">
  <meta name="description" content="Description">
```

But it doesn't work. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the way of button works! i.e: for whatsapp btn, if the client has the whatsapp app on his computer, then it will launch the app. but if not, then the web site web.whatsapp.com . On other hand, when the client click on Messenger button while using phone; it will launch the Messenger app but not on desktop because there is no Messenger app installed on it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).